# Web application with node that runs and manages background job

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, job-scheduling

I have a requirement that goes like this:
- Receive http post request with data, let a function or a instance of a script do something with that data. It takes time to run the job so once the job is finished save the result in mongodb and sends an email to the address provided in that post request.

Between Python and Node.js what are some libraries/frameworks I can look at for relative ease in developing web application that does something like this as well as manage ( start, stop, edit, delete task).

Comment: read about using a worker for your longer process : https://github.com/nolanlawson/promise-worker